# How can we make a single key binding to go to matching bracket, and also emmet matching tag?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

We can currently go to a matching bracket with <kbd>cmd+shift+\</kbd>. And there's also a command called `Emmet: Go To Matching Pair` to go to a matching HTML tag.

How can we make the <kbd>cmd+shift+\</kbd> keyboard shortcut (or any key shortcut) do both matching brackets and Emmet matching tags?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for (in your keybindings.json):

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+\\",
    "command": "editor.action.jumpToBracket",
    "when": "resourceExtname != .html"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+\\",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.matchTag",
    "when": "resourceExtname == .html"
  },
```

This would do the emmet `matchTag` command in an `.html` file and do the `jumpToBracket` command in any other type of file.

Comment: Nice! Does the .html need to be in quotes? Is the `when` value a JavaScript code string?

Comment: Hmm, what about while inside JSX in a JavaScript file? Or in a template string with html syntax enabled (f.e. with the lit-html plugin)?

Comment: The "when" clauses do need to be in quotes.  You can use regex on the file extension with a slightly different syntax but you can't differentiate inside one file between html within another filetype and outside that contained html.  It only looks at the file extension so it is all or none.

Comment: Ah ok. Dang. Would be nice if it was per syntax. About the quotes, I meant, does it need to be `"resourceExtname == '.html'"` with the quotes around the `'.html'`?

Comment: No, `"when": "resourceExtname == .html"` is correct.

Comment: What language is inside the quotes?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts for more.